# List.remove() x not in list while trying to make pokemon game

Tags: python

Although the line is now redundant, however upon running a few iterations, the line that is supposed to remove self.y from the original list raised 'Valueerror : list.remove(x) x not in list. I cant's figure out what I did wrong here now.

```
from random import sample, choice


class Selection(object):


    def __init__(self):

        self.pokemon_list = [
            'Blastoise', 'Charizard', 'Venasaur',   
            'Artiquno', 'Moltress', 'Zapdos', 
        ]

        self.x = sample(self.pokemon_list, 3)

        print """
    CONGRATULATIONS TRAINER, YOU HAVE BEEN GIVEN %s,
    YOUR JOURNEY BEGINS NOW! PROCEED WISELY OR DIE.
    """ % (self.x)


    def gary_pok(self):

        for self.z in self.x:

            if self.z == "Blastoise":
                self.y = 'Venasaur'
                **self.pokemon_list.remove(self.y)
                print self.pokemon_list**
            elif self.z == "Charizard":
                self.y = 'Blastoise'
                print self.pokemon_list.remove(self.y)
            elif self.z == "Venasaur":
                self.y = 'Charizard'
                print self.pokemon_list.remove(self.y)
            else:
                self.y = choice(self.pokemon_list)
                print self.pokemon_list.remove(self.y)

        print "Gary's pokemons:{}, Nidoqueen and Archanine.".format(self.y)

bah = Selection()
bah.gary_pok()
```

Comment: Do you call `bah.gary_pok()` multiple times?

Comment: I did yes. Oh i got it thank you.

Answer (score -2):

When you are looping over, you can't remove an item from the list.
Because, when it falls to your condition when loop is happening first time, it will remove item from your list, when loop is going second iteration, it wants to remove item which already was removed.

[image]

After Artiquioni is printed,`Charizard` is removed, then in next iteration, `Charizard` not on the list

Comment: They are not looping over the same list they are removing from. Also, do not post images of code, post code as formatted text

Comment: The code posted is not the same problem. Also you are calling remove on a string.

Comment: Got it, sorry :-)